# 9 Patch Buttons in Android 4.0 are too tall

Tags: android, button, nine-patch

I have 9 patch buttons for my app, in Android 2.3 they are displayed properly, but when I try in my devices with Android 4.0 the buttons are too tall, and i need them like in Android 2.3.

They are in `wrap_content` in the layout.

Image in android 2.3: http://picturepush.com/public/12502980
Image in android 4.0: http://picturepush.com/public/12502985
My 9patch button: http://picturepush.com/public/12502990

What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you provide the layout's XML snippet for your button?

Comment: Ok you are putting the images in which folder like drwable-ldpi,drwable-hdpi,drwable-xdpi,drwable-mdpiand tell me your device resolution..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the 9-patch and everything to do with the Button widget, themes, etc.

Probably the easiest way to fix this is to set the `Min Height` attribute to `0dp` in the layout designer.